# PHP Unable to insert data into database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert data given by the user into the database when I use simple mysqli it works perfectly but when I use PDO data is inserted into the database.

```
<?php

$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'db';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$name = '';
$password = '';
$email = '';
$uid = '';

$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,userid) VALUES(?,?,?, ?)";
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $newpass = hash("sha256", $password);
    if ($name != '' && $password != '' && $email != '') {
        $insertUser = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $insertUser->execute($name, $email, $password, $uid);
    }
}

$conn = null;
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: @ADyson No I am not getting any error.

Comment: This should give you an error `execute($name, $email, $password, $uid)`

Comment: So please explain us what happens when you run this code. Which line of it gets executed?

Comment: Maybe you have error reporting switched off in PHP then? Because you should definitely be seeing one, as Dharman notes. Either that or the code is not entering one of your `if` blocks, and therefore `execute` never runs. Done any debugging?

Comment: I think my query statement is wrong.  Can I replace it with this                                 
     `$data = [
   'name' => $name,
   'email' => $email,
   'password' => $newpass,
   'uid' => $uid,
  ];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,userid) VALUES(:name, :email, :password, :uid)";
  $insertUser = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $insertUser->execute($data);`

Comment: Yes that would be better. Please try it. But also, another thing, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Equally don't use any old hashing. Learn about PHP's built-in [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your advice and cooperation my problem has solved Thank you.

Comment: @ADyson what if we want to validate that data that user has entered is not present in database I am using select query in similar manner but unable to monitor the result of select query if you have any idea please share.                                                   `$checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  email = ?";   $checkUser =  $conn->prepare($checkUser);   $checktUser->execute($email);`

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post about it. Questions cannot be answered via comments, thanks. Hint: "unable to" isn't an error message or problem statement though. When you make your post, make clear what you've tried and what went wrong. You can find plenty of examples using SELECT queries in PDO, if you want to know how to get the result. It's not hard to look it up. So if you have a specific issue, you need to show that you tried to use some code you've researched.

Comment: @ADyson I have reached my questions limit so I am unable to post another question kindly consider

Comment: That's not my problem, sorry. Just wait till you are allowed to ask again. I won't get any reputation from helping in the comments, it's hard to post code or  much detail, and also others cannot help you either, and future users cannot search your question if they have similar issues. It's just a bad way to do it. Besides as I've said above (I've edited the comment now) it's easy to research how to get the result from a PDO select query. You'd need to be a lot more specific about what your actual issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parameters array:

```php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,userid) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $newpass = hash("sha256", $password);
        if($name!='' && $password!='' && $email!='')
        {
            $insertUser = $conn->prepare($sql);
            // use ARRAY instead plain variables
            $insertUser->execute([$name, $email, $password,  $uid]);
        }
    }
```

[Execute PHP online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=adfa7d74813b81dc96dac8e36ce50a09&sqlses=4ec8663e9fbb1a1e58ac7f8ce9b2c587&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: what if we want to validate that data that user has entered is not present in database I am using select query in similar manner but unable to monitor the result of select query if you have any idea please share.    `$checkUser1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  email = ?";
  $checkUser =  $conn->prepare($checkUser);
  $checktUser->execute($email);`

Comment: Use `$stmt->rowCount();` https://phpize.online/?phpses=72a3a5e715f19ee0f1a2f885f2b55e91&sqlses=4ec8663e9fbb1a1e58ac7f8ce9b2c587&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: i tried in this way but now I'm unable to insert the data.  https://phpize.online/?phpses=c8c207cb117d9ee738bfdd84618519fe&sqlses=4ec8663e9fbb1a1e58ac7f8ce9b2c587&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: Your code work perfect, look it here: https://phpize.online/?phpses=8b2fd79a3d6167e21598de827a40538e&sqlses=4ec8663e9fbb1a1e58ac7f8ce9b2c587&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: done thank you so much for your cooperation